# How do I set up an if statement to animate a sprite?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, sdl

How can I set up an if statement so after every frame the sprite shows the next frame and then the next and then once it goes through all the frames it is over?

I tried using if statements and it has never worked for me, could anyone give an example?

Edit:

After demand for code I have decided to add a sample.

```
int frame4 = 1;

if(frame4 = 1)
{
WalkDownFrame1(); //Renders frame 4
}
else if(frame4 = 2)
{
WalkDownFrame2(); //Renders frame 2
}
else if(frame4 = 3)
{
WalkDownFrame3(); //Renders frame 3
}
else if(frame4 = 4)
{
WalkDownFrame4(); //Renders frame 4
}
else if(frame4 = 5)
{
frame4 = 1;
}
frame4++;
```

no matter what modifications I apply it stays stuck on one frame.

Comment: We won't be able to help you without knowing what you've already done. Please post the code.

Comment: possibly a loop can help. for example a **while**.

Comment: @PawełStawarz Done and done.

Comment: `static int frame4 = 1;` so it keeps its value the next time the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean if the conditions are true the animation occurs and if the conditions are false it stops, in which case it would look like

```
/*Rest of your model transformation code*/
if(shouldbeanimating){
   /*animation code*/
}else{
/*default state or nothing if you want the model to 
freeze at that point in the animation*/
}
```

Then whenever the program should stop the animation you just set shouldbeanimating to false

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to know how many frames your animation has. Then you proceed to draw frame after frame. If you hit the last frame you go back to the first or you stop. 
Here's a link that will help you. It's doesnt matter if its SDL or any other lib, the approach is always the same.
http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson20/index.php

As an example

```
while(isAnimating)
{
   framecounter++;
   isAnimating = (framecounter < MAX_FRAMES);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They're many solutions. You can do a Sprite Class and add an attribute _tick, store your Texture into a container, like  a std::vector. I'll give you a short hint. You put a method tick() to increment your tick number. You put an attribute nbFrames, that contains the number of frames for the current sprite.

```
int tick;
int nbFrames; //equivalent of textures.size()
std::vector<SDL_Texture*> textures;
SDL_Texture *idle_frame;
bool moving;
int x;
int y;


Sprite::Sprite()
{
  _tick = 0;
  //init your textures
  moving = false;
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
}

int _tick;

void Sprite::tick(void)
{
    // Consider that _tick can reach the Max Value of int32
   _tick++;
}

void Sprite::render(void)
{
   SDL_Texture *texture;

   if(moving)
   {
      int fr_index = _tick % nbFrames;
      texture = textures[fr_index];
   } 
   else
   {
      texture = idle_frame;
   }

   //then you do your render code with SDL_RenderCopy, or OpenGL code
   //.
   //..
}
```

Still missing some other thing to handle, but that an hint for your solution.

Comment: If you want a more complete solution, I can give you a link to some source code of my GitHub repository.

Comment: Yes please! I tried implementing your data but it still only shows one frame.

Comment: https://github.com/jordsti/stiuniverse/tree/master/StiGame , browse this folder, you will see some class that I wrote to handle sprite.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are just assigning in the if statement and not testing? Or did you just miss typed it here?

Because if your code is if(frame = 0) it should be (frame == 0).

Comment: yup I solved it, but lost my ability to ask questions for asking something so simple.